# Angular2 - Global view function

Tags: angular

I am coming to NG2 from NG1. In NG1, everything that you put in the parent's scope is accessible by the child scope, and it's views.

I am now facing a problem:
I have timestamps in multiple components, and I want to run a function for all, that will say "X minutes ago".

What is the best practice in this case?

Using `@Input()` is not possible, because it happens by the router.

Using a global service, and from every single component to publicly inject it is not a very nice solution either (not the amount of work, but the amount of mess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that such thing can't be done, unless you use a base class and all of your components extend it.

What I do, is using a global variable, I inject the parameters I want (as pointers) into the relevant component.

You can look at it as redundant coding, but I can really appreciate it now, as it is very organised.